# How to use circle detect in a video

Tags: opencv

I'm very new to python and OpenCV. What I am trying to do is find a circle on a part in a video using the hough circles and track that circle as it moves across the cameras field of view. I can use the hough circles on a still image. This is what I have so far, but I don't think it is anywhere close to being working.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                        param1=200,param2=100,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

For a video analysis you have to read images from your webcam (in this case) continuously. So you need a loop as shown in the tutorials from [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html#lucas-kanade).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

     #read frame from capture
     img = cap.read()

     ##############################
     # here do the whole stuff with circles and your actual image
     ##############################

     cv2.imshow('show image', img)

     #exit condition to leave the loop
     k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
     if k == 27:
          break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```